# Java Program only runs in IDE, not exported as a Jar

Tags: java, jar

I can run my software without any problems in my IDE, but when I try to compile it to a jar, and try to run it, it says that the main class can't be found. I succeeded to make it work perfectly several times in the past, but I found this problem few time ago, so I can't really know when it went wrong.
The jar has a META-INF, all properly set up, like in my older versions, and the main class is there. Other peoples can't compile too, so it's not just me. The code is on Github, so that could be a tool to help me solve this.

But I want to know, just by reading this, is there some common mistakes that could cause this, or this is uncommon?

EDIT:
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA
and I will check if the versions are the same.

EDIT2:
They do have the same version, and it's exporting an executable jar with the correct main class defined, as I have beeing doing for all the previous versions.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?  Many IDEs, e.g. Eclipse, have built-in options to export to executable JAR.

Comment: How are you exporting it to a jar using *jar* command OR using IDE feature?

Comment: I am exporting a jar with the IDE settings, but I tried to make a jar using the command prompt too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the MANIFEST.MF is present in the META-INF folder of the jar, and make sure that the line :

```
Main-Class: yourMainClass
```

is present inside the file, then make sure that you start the jar with this command line :

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

Have you tried to launch the jar file specifying the main class ? For example :

```
java yourjar.jar yourMainClass
```

Does it work in this way ?

Comment: Didn't worked, but thanks for your help, I found out it was an error totally unrelated to the manifest or the jar, but an error in the actual code.