# Jar Distributable Not working

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, build, jar

I've developed an app using DropboxAPI in Netbeans and i'm using Swing to build a GUI.

The app works fine if I run it from IDE but when after I clean&build it, the .jar file in /dist won't open at all.

So I've opened my command line and I've got this error

```
java -jar "%PATH_TO_MY_APP%\FileTransferSpeedMonitor.jar"
Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file %PATH_TO_MY_APP\FileTransferSpeedMonitor.jar
```

So I decided to make multiple searches with different keywords but to no avail.
The strangest thing is that when I try to run the .class files that have a static void main method inside them, I get an error that no main method is defined although it works fine from IDE.

I'm not sure if the mismatch below is relevant because other swing apps are working fine (ex: Celsius Fahrenheit tutorial), anyways, my app doesn't seem to throw any exceptions or any sign that something is wrong but I need to find out what's causing all this.

```
C:\Users>java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and Netbeans 7.3.1

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 (Build 201306052037)
Java: 1.7.0_05; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.1-b03
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_05-b05
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
...
```

later edit #1 - added manifest.mf data

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_05-b05 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/dropbox-core-sdk-1.7.5-javadoc.jar lib/dropbox-core-sd
 k-1.7.5-sources.jar lib/dropbox-core-sdk-1.7.5.jar lib/jackson-core-2
 .2.3.jar lib/org-apache-commons-io.jar
X-COMMENT : Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: dbftsm.swing.ExploreDBX
```

later edit #2 - added output from CLI , not making any sense at all

```
%path_to_buld%\dist>java FileTransferSpeedMonitor.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class FileTransferSpeedMonitor.jar
```

Comment: Does your jar's manifest file contain the appropriate class-path information, especially to the DropboxAPI libraries?

Comment: If you use third party libraries, validate is your build contains that libraries.

Comment: added manifest data , mind if you take a look?

Comment: tried writing a custom manifest and edited project.properties but i get the same error

Comment: trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142988/java-program-only-runs-in-ide-not-exported-as-a-jar

Comment: almost solved, will check the if the manifest looks different ... see my comment below

Comment: Use `java -jar FileTransferSpeedMonitor.jar` instead of `java FileTransferSpeedMonitor.jar`

Comment: tried that, you get the same error, i build the project with eclipse and it worked, i need to check if netbeans manifest differs from eclipse manifest and see what is actually the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest file must be in JAR with exact location `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

Your `dist` folder must contain all required dependencies in a `lib` folder, typically:

```
%path_to_buld%\dist\lib\dropbox-core-sdk-1.7.5.jar
%path_to_buld%\dist\lib\jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
%path_to_buld%\dist\lib\org-apache-commons-io.jar
```

It does not make sense to declare `-sources.jar` or `-javadoc.jar` in `Class-Path` attribute.

Your last test error message is explained by the lack of the `-jar` option.

Comment: didn't try because I've decided to uninstall all JDK's and Netbeans, install latest JDK+JRE and migrated my project to Eclipse Kepler and it works now ... I will check now hpw the manifest file looks now